# entering text in a file at specific locations by identifying the number being integer or real in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have an input like below

```
    46742       1   48276   48343   48199   48198
    46744       1   48343   48344   48200   48199
    46746       1   48344   48332   48201   48200
    48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
    48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
    48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
```

Each segment with the 2nd entry like 1 being integer is like thousands of lines and then starts the segment with the 2nd entry being real like 3.58077402e+01

Before anything beings I have to input a text like

```
*Revolved
*Gripped
*Crippled
    46742       1   48276   48343   48199   48198
    46744       1   48343   48344   48200   48199
    46746       1   48344   48332   48201   48200
*Cracked
*Crippled
    48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
    48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
    48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
```

so I need to enter specific texts at those locations. It is worth mentioning that the file is space delimited and not tabs delimited and that the text starting with * has to be at the very left of the line without spacing. The format of the rest of the file should be kept too.

Any suggestions with sed or awk would be highly appreaciated!
The text in the beginning could entered directly so that is not a prime problem since that is the start of the file, problematic is the second bunch of line so identify that the second entry has turned to real.

Comment: You really need to get into the habit of telling people you cannot use GNU awk.

Comment: its evening here in my office and the IT guys got office in the afternoon, I have to go through that, combine the code and let the simulations run...  that satire is unfortunate as if it were, i would have got it installed right away... just waiting for them till tomorrow and would get it installed, i marked your words :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `awk` with fixed strings:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "*Revolved\n*Gripped\n*Crippled"}
     match($2,"\+")&&!pr{print "*Cracked\n*Crippled";pr=1}1' yourfile
```

`match($2,"\+")&&!pr` : When `+` char is found at `$2` field(real number) and `pr` flag is `null`.

Comment: it gives  everything added to the top only, it didnt get the last two words printed over the first occurance of real number in the second field.. and further in order to generalize it can your suggest a general integral check? because there might not be always 1, could be 2 ,3 4,5, 13 any integer, so when that ends and the real number starts, then I want to add that second group of text

Comment: this trick would help me to solve alot of problems, I like this match stuff. I would analyse it for alot of case, thanks !